# how do I get css animation to work on element

Tags: html, css

Trying to run an animation on the paragraph with id='hello,' but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

I've added some other elements where the animation worked, but it doesn't work on this specific element. I can't seem to figure out why.

**CSS Code:**

```css
body{
    background: linear-gradient(35deg,skyblue,limegreen);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}


@keyframes slideup {
    from{
        transform: translateX(1000px);
    }
    to{
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
 }

 .hello{
    animation-name: slideup;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
 }
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Title</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="sttyle.css">
            
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 id="heading1">Web heading</h1>
    
            <p id="hello">hello</p>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Change .hello to #hello (# is for id) (. is for classes)

Comment: another potential typo could be "sttyle.css", unless you named your CSS file this

Answer (score 1):

You are targetting a class name of 'hello' instead of an id of 'hello'.
Change the css to:

```
 #hello{
    animation-name: slideup;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
 }
```

Comment: '#' is the css selector for an id, and '.' is the selector for a class.
[guide to css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors/Selectors_and_combinators)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm  a css noob so I do make some dumb mistakes at times

Comment: np :P, we all do